# Is it possible to 'relay' a socket?

Tags: c#, java, .net, sockets, networking

I was wondering it it was possible to relay a socket object in either C# or Java? (Preferably C#)

I have lots of little programs i make and host them on my home pc, but my pc is behind a router, so i have to forward a port on my router every time i want to make a new application. So is there a way to send a tcp connection to another application on the same computer? for instance i get a connection in with the first line of text being `RELAY::21005` which would then forward that port to `localhost:21005` ?

Any help, tutorials, code snippets would be much appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: Not sure you want an outside program telling your computer what ports to open.  But you're kind of describing a proxy service, so you could probably dig up some simple open source proxy project and see how they're forwarding data.  And this is also kinda what ssh tunneling is all about, so you could employ that instead.

Comment: How would ssh tunneling allow sharing a port?

Comment: @sixfeetsix - the `-L` and `-R` options open a listening port on one machine, and forward connections to a port on another machine. There are a lot of questions about this on superuser: http://superuser.com/search?q=ssh+tunnel

Comment: @parsifal: Once again, how does that allow to do something like port sharing?

Comment: @sixfeetsix - have you read the documentation for ssh? Do you have specific questions about what you read? Because it's pretty clear about how tunneling works.

Comment: @parsifal: I know exactly what tunneling and reverse-tunneling is and how it works; now if you read the question from the OP further than just the title, you'll notice how he actually wants to "share" some port; so for the 3rd time, how are you going to do that with ssh? In you answer, how does ssh end up making a difference?

Comment: I don't see why ssh shouldn't do exactly what the OP requested. Have one port open on the router which redirects to the ssh port on the PC. ssh in from your "remote" machine specifying multiple "-L" arguments like "-L 1234:localhost:1234 -L 1235:localhost:1235" and then you've got access to 2 apps on the home PC with only one router port forwarding. You get security as well.

Comment: I give up. My interpretation of "I was wondering it it was possible to relay a socket object in either C# or Java? (Preferably C#)" and "So is there a way to send a tcp connection to another application on the same computer?" must be faulty; or oh wait, is this another case of "let's not stick to what the OP asks cause I'm know better than her/him?"

Comment: @sixfeetsix: you might want to read the _second_ paragraph of the question again. That tells you what the OP wanted to *achieve*. Ssh port forwarding would achieve the OP's goals as I understand them (although not using the mechanism the OP had in mind).

Comment: @Paul Cager: AFAICT, you and parsifal are using what is in my opinion an overly wide interpretation of the OP's question to push ssh, that's all.

Comment: @sixfeetsix: perhaps you do truly understand the OP's desires and the rest of us don't. But unless you can explain what "send a tcp connection" means, I'll stick with my interpretation.

Comment: @parsifal: I don't agree that given the context SSH makes sense; you are adding a layer and also you are forcing the clients to ssh in. As for my sarcasm, you started it by "have you read the documentation for ssh"; and ultimately I think that yes you don't understand what makes sense for the OP in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you might face with your suggested solution (first line identifies target port) is that you'll have to change all of your client programs to send that first line. That's easy for programs you've written yourself but not so convenient if you want to connect to your PC's web server or ssh daemon etc. It's not impossible of course, but does make it hard.

I'd suggest your routing server listens on two ports - a control port and a "normal" port (I can't think of a better name at the moment). You would send control messages to the control port to indicate "until further notice redirect all incoming connections on the normal port to port nnnn". That avoids having to manipulate client protocols.

I don't know enough C# to provide advice about a C# solution, but in Java I'd simply do something like:

```
while (true) {
    acceptConnectionOnNormalPort()
    connectToTargetPort()
    startThreadCopyingDataFromAcceptedPortToTargetPort()
    startThreadCopyingDataFromTargetPortToAcceptedPort()
}
```

You'd not be able to scale that easily into thousands of connections...

Answer (score 0):

K I take back my comment, check this out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395195.aspx

Using this requires the port sharing service [to be up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733925.aspx) (it is disabled by default):

> The Net.TCP Port Sharing Service is available on all operating systems
>   that support .NET Framework 3.0, but the service is not enabled by
>   default.

All of this is only useful to you if you are using WCF services tho.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach IMO is to use ssh tunneling. As I wrote in my comment, there are lots of questions on SU that will show you how to do this.

But assuming that you want to program something ...

You'll need to create a client and a server. The client will have threads that call `accept` on whatever local ports you want to open. When a connection comes to a port, you create another thread that opens a connection to the server and continually sends data over the wire.

The server program listens on a single port, which you open in your firewall. It waits for connections on that port, and when it receives one it opens a connection to the specified local port. Then it shuffles bytes from one to the other.

The only trick is that you have to define a protocol for specifying the destination port in the client-server stream. Simplest approach is to write a two-byte integer at the start of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to relay a socket.
You can use TURN http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relay_NAT

Some of TURN library/application:

- pjnath
- turnserver.sourceforge.net